# Jelastic maven plugin throws gateway time-out on deploy goal

Tags: maven, spring-boot, jelastic

I'm using jelastic to build and deploy spring-boot application with a many classes. It takes few minutes for jelastic to redeploy this application. But when environment starts reloading after plugin execution - plugin throws Gateway time-out.

Here is plugin configuration:

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.jelastic</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jelastic-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${jelastic-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>deploy</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <email>${jelastic-maven-plugin.login}</email>
                        <password>${jelastic-maven-plugin.password}</password>
                        <context>${jelastic-maven-plugin.context}</context>
                        <environment>${jelastic-maven-plugin.environment-name}</environment>
                        <comment />
                        <api_hoster>${jelastic-maven-plugin.hoster-api}</api_hoster>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

Here is log from console (I removed File URL from this trace, but I've checked - it was valid):

```
[INFO] [94%]
[INFO] [95%]
[INFO] [96%]
[INFO] [97%]
[INFO] [98%]
[INFO] [99%]
[INFO] [100%]
[INFO]       File UpLoad : SUCCESS
[INFO]          File URL : http://{{host}}/xssu/rest/download/{{fileid}}
[INFO]         File size : 61768307
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] File registration : SUCCESS
[INFO]   Registration ID : 16518
[INFO]      Developer ID : 1431
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Gateway Time-out
org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Gateway Time-out
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:67)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:55)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:945)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:919)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:910)
    at com.jelastic.JelasticMojo.deploy(JelasticMojo.java:667)
    at com.jelastic.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:40)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:18.859s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Jul 30 11:26:03 MSK 2017
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.jelastic:jelastic-maven-plugin:1.8.1:deploy (default-cli) on project dance-form: Execution default-cli of goal com.jelastic:jelastic-maven-plugin:1.8.1:deploy failed. NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

I checked in console that environment was reloaded as the result of this execution. 
How can I increase time-out in jelastic maven plugin?

Comment: Could you please provide us with just an environment name so will be able to check?

Comment: @Jelastic sure, it is env-6369893, hoster is mycloud

Comment: our devs are investigating this issue right now. We will inform you once we have this problem fixed or in case of other results

Comment: we have found the issue and it is already fixed, please check

Comment: @Jelastic thanks,now 1.8.2 version works well!